# Read ZipFile from android DocumentFile Efficiently

Tags: java, android

Reading a file from an android device in an external Storage.
I have the document uri of the file by using [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) . 
The file happens to be a zip file and I here is a snippet I am using to read the zip file :

```
private File readDataFromZip(Context context, String zipPath, String name, String ext) {
    ZipFile zipFile = null;
    try {
        if (ProjectApplication.getInstance().SAF_MODE) {
            UserModel userModel = UserQuery.getUserById(context, SharedPref.getCurrentUser(context));
            DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, Uri.parse(SharedPref.getSAF(context, userModel, "data")));

            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(documentFile.getUri());
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.e("field", entry.getName());
                if (entry.getName().contains(name)) {
                    File file =  PBUtils.writeByteArraysToFile(ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipInputStream), ext);
                    inputStream.close();
                    return file;
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();

        } else {
            zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("data/" + name);
            if (zipEntry != null) {
                return writeByteArraysToFile(ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)), ext);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

This works well, except that it reading through the content is very slow when using input stream on **SAF_MODE**.

Is there a faster way I can read a zipFile using **[DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html)**

Comment: `zipFile.getInputStream(entry)`. NullPointerException in saf mode.

Comment: this works, except that looking for a file is very slow.

Comment: NullPointerExceptions are usually not equal to 'it works'.

Comment: What did you edit? zipFile==null in saf mode. Still.

Comment: the SAF_MODE does not have any null check. uses the documentFile to get an inputStream for ZipInputStream. File is been retrieved but it's slow.

Comment: Yes i can see that too. But you are using a null pointer. zipFile is null is what i tried to tell you. You will have a NullPointerException if the `name` is found.

Comment: oh, I see @greenapps. fixed. Thanks. Still slow though

Comment: `here is a snippet I am using to read the zip file `. But you are also writing the readed data directly to a 'normal' file. So how do you know where the time is spent?

Comment: What is time consuming? getNextEntry() or reading from inputstream? You should investigate and tell us. I know that DocumentFile is slow listing files and so.  But i have never experienced that reading from its input stream is slow.  What is the bottle neck in your code?

Comment: yea, I just create a temp file if the file is found and directly read from the temp file. I ran the code on debug. The zip file has many files in it, some files happen to be a media file that is kinda large, when running through the list of files, there's a delay.

Comment: @greenapps getNextEntry() is time cosuming

Comment: `ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipInputStream)` That will make a byte array of the complete rest of the zip. Not only of the intended entry. So what are you doing?

Comment: `and directly read from the temp file`. ? Why? And where? This also would take time.

Comment: To better compare with the non saf code i suggest you a test using getNextEntry() too there. Instead of getEntry().

Comment: the NON_SAF_MODE works really fast. Beside, I just tested by taking out ByteStreams.toByteArray(zipInputStream) and returning an emptyFile instead, still slow getNextEntry()  seems to be the culprit. Notice if getNextEntry()  is a large media file inside the zip, it takes more time to execute the next getNextEntry()

Comment: Again: replace getEntry by getNextEntry. Make both code blocks as equal as possible. After that you know who to blame.